# Klein routes don't return anything

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes

I've got this code in my index.php

```
 <?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$router = new \Klein\Klein();

$router->respond('/hello-world', function () {
    return 'Hello World!';
});

$router->dispatch();
```

and htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

and when i try to open /hello-world (or index.php/hello-world) it just gives me a blank white screen.
If i have only this route:

```
$router->respond(function () {
    return 'All the things';
});
```

it works on index.php/ but not on /

I'm looking for a long time but can't see whats wrong?

Comment: That's a good question. It seems to not be responding to your $_GET variables. Have you got this figured out yet?

Comment: Is it possible your Apache config is setup so that .htaccess cannot override it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this and change /path/to/app with your real path to the app

```
 define('APP_PATH', '/path/to/app');
 require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
 $request = \Klein\Request::createFromGlobals();
 $request->server()->set('REQUEST_URI', substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],  strlen(APP_PATH)));
 $klein = new \Klein\Klein();

 $klein->respond('GET', '/hello', function () {
     return 'Hello World!';
 });

 $klein->dispatch($request);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the rewrite does not work. Just try to echo something simple in the php without any framework like so:

**index.php** (only these three lines)

```
<?php 
    echo 'does it work?';
?>
```

Then try to call something like /hello-world. If it does not show your message, maybe your host does not support mod_redirect.

You should be able to display all activated apache modules with the function `apache_get_modules`:

```
<?php
    print_r(apache_get_modules());
?>
```

There should be mod_rewrite listed.